# Kafka Dynamic Producer giving error in unsecured cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to create kafka producer to push data from spring api into topic.

The structure of class is as follows :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/kafka/{topicName}/{message}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendToTopic(
            @Parameter(description = "Topic name", required = true) @PathVariable String topicName,
            @Parameter(description = "Message to send", required = true) @PathVariable String message) {
        String currentMessage = "";
        currentMessage = messageService.publishSync(topicName, message);
        LOGGER.debug("Published successfully message (200) into topic {}", topicName);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(currentMessage);
    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Kafka kafkaConfig;
    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Producer<String, KafkaMessage> createProducer() {
        final Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBootstrapServers());
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaMessage.class.getName());
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "ABC");
        configs.put("retries", "3");
        configs.put("linger.ms", "5");
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        return new KafkaProducer<>(configs);

    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, KafkaMessage> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessage> kafkaTemplate(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(kafkaProperties));
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class MessageService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageService.class);

    private ObjectFactory<Producer<String, KafkaMessage>> producer;
    private KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessage> kafkaTemplate;

    public MessageService(ObjectFactory<Producer<String, KafkaMessage>> producer,
                          KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessage> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.producer = producer;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public String publishSync(final @NotEmpty String topicName, final @NotNull String message) {
        return publishRawMessage(topicName, message, false);
    }

    private @NotNull String publishRawMessage(final @NotEmpty String topicName,
                                              final @NotNull String message,
                                              final boolean async) {

        KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = new KafkaMessage();
        kafkaMessage.setId(UUID.randomUUID().hashCode());
        kafkaMessage.setMessage(message);

        ProducerRecord<String, KafkaMessage> record = null;
        record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, kafkaMessage);
        Producer<String, KafkaMessage> localProducer = producer.getObject();
        try {
            if (async) {
                localProducer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
                    LOGGER.info("Record ASYNCHRONOUSLY sent to partition {} with offset {}",
                            metadata.partition(), metadata.offset());
                }).get();
            } else {
                RecordMetadata metadata = localProducer.send(record).get();
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Execution Error in sending record", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Interrupted Error in sending record", e);
        } finally {
            localProducer.flush();
            localProducer.close();
        }

        return "Successfully Inserted"+message;
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class KafkaMessage {
    Integer id;
    String message;
}
```

I am getting following error while running this api:

> 2022-07-07 18:19:40.560  WARN 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createProducer' defined in class path resource [org/kafka/producer/KafkaProducerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer]: Factory method 'createProducer' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer]

```
2022-07-07 18:19:40.555  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = ABC
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer
    linger.ms = 5
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 3
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.kafka.producer.KafkaMessage

2022-07-07 18:19:40.557  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=ABC] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2022-07-07 18:19:40.557  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-07-07 18:19:40.557  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-07-07 18:19:40.557  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-07-07 18:19:40.558  INFO 20540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.producer for ABC unregistered
```